# Read any file from DRL file Drools

Tags: java, json, xml, drools

Is there any way to read or parse any file format ex: JSON or XML from DRL file Drools ? for example:

```
when 
SomeClass()
read any file type JSON or XML

then
Do something
```

Comment: What does "read any file" mean in this context? What do you expect Drools to do with the file?  This is very unclear.

Comment: I want to know is it possible to parse or read json or xml file that not from class file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You will need to read and parse the file as you want outside of the DRL and then feed the results of the parsing into your session.

You can also do the parsing in the RHS of a rule if you want.

Hope it helps,